# F(x) + f(x+.5) = 1

Tags: functions

Our teacher told us that the Function is actually unique and it is a constant function.
Is he right? If not then please give a counter example.

Comment: Assumptions, such as continuous?  If not, there are easy counterexamples.

Comment: No there are no assumptions but I don't know if he comes up with a explanation of his own with the added constraints

Answer (score 1):

Say $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x \rfloor$, then the function $$ f(x)= \left\{%
\begin{array}{ll}
    a, & 0\leq \{x\}<{1\over 2}, \\
    1-a, & {1\over 2}\leq \{x\} <1.\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$satisfies the condition and it is not constant.

**Comment:** Any function that satisfies a given condition must be periodic with period 1:

$$ F(x+{1\over 2})-F(x-{1\over 2}) =  \underbrace{F(x+{1\over 2})-F(x)}_{=1}+\underbrace{F(x)-F(x-{1\over 2})}_{=1}  =0$$

Comment: By $a$ you mean $\{ x \}$, right?

Comment: No, $a$ is an arbitrary constant and $\{x\}$ is a fraction part of $x$.

Comment: Got it. But if we plugged in $\{x\}$ instead of $a$ it would also work, with the advantage of it becoming a continuous function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a continuous example, here's a slight modification of the idea in John Watsons example: Let $\{x\} = x - \lfloor x\rfloor$ and
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}\{x\} & \text{if} \ 0\leq \{x\} < \frac12 \\ 1 - \{x\} & \text{if} \ \frac12 \leq \{x\} < 1 \end{cases}$$
I suspect there's even a way to smooth this out so that it's infinitely differentiable, an appropriate scaling and normalization of the sine function maybe?  I'm not gonna figure out the formula though.

**Edit:** Ok, I was intrigued and went and figured out the formula.  The following works and is smooth:
$$f(x) = \sin(2\pi x) + \frac12$$
Smooth functions are about as nice as they come, so I doubt your teacher has anything reasonable in mind as a condition under which there are only constant solutions to that equation.  Maybe he made a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f: \left[0,\frac12\right] \to \mathbb{R}$ be any function satisfying $ f(\frac12) = 1 - f(0)$, and $$f^{(n)}(0) = f^{(n)}(1/2) = 0$$
for every $n \geq 1$, where $f^{(n)}(x)$ denotes the $n$-th derivative of $f$.

Now let $g:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $f(x)$ on $[0,\frac12]$ and $1 - f\left(x - \frac12\right)$ on $[\frac12, 1]$.

Finally, setting $F(x) = g\left(x - \lfloor x \rfloor\right)$ we get a smooth solution for the equation.